# How to read JSON and write to Console

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file and I want to store his data, print it in a console. I'm trying doing this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public string age { get; set;}
    public string address { get; set;}
}

public void readJson() 
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\json\response.json");
    Person p = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
}
```

How can I read all the people? How can I write all the results in console?

Comment: If the json contains multiple `Person` objects, then your deserialization is not correct  (you need a type that maches the json string, probably a `List<Person>` or `Content` that has a list of Person).

Comment: @Russe there is a lot of information on the Internet about this especially since you are using the `Newtonsoft.Json.Convert` method look at their documentation located here explains clearly how to do this http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Person
    {

        public string name { get; set;}
        public string age { get; set;}
        public string address { get; set;}
    }

    public void readJson() 
    {
        try
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\json\response.json");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        //TODO:Log or something
        }
        IEnumerable<Person> pList = new List<Person>(); 

        try
        {
        pList =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Person>>(json);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO:Log or something
        }

        forach(var person in pList)
        {
            Console.ReadLine(person);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to instantiate a `List<Person>` as that object will just be discarded when you deserialize into `pList`.

Comment: Once you write it in a "try", there is no way to access it outside it unless it was declared somewhere else in the code. It happens because maybe you caught an Exception before it was  instantiated (So its null). i had one bad though, and it was ReadLine instead of WriteLine....

Comment: You can declare it outside the try, you just don't need to instantiate it. You're creating an object that two lines later will be abandoned for garbage collection.

Comment: Once i delete the instancing i receive :use of unassigned local variable" compiling error.. i replaced IEnumerable<Person> pList = new List<Person>();  to IEnumerable<Person> pList;

Comment: Instead of assigning `new`, just set `pList = null;` -> `IEnumerable<Person> pList = null;` (Also, you might not want to try/catch each part but have one around both the reading and serializing).